# Airbnb hosts wants me to send pictures of all guests' IDs

Tags: passports, italy, airbnb

This is my first booking using the Airbnb app and when I signed up I had to take pictures of me and my government ID. I invited all my friends who are staying with me and they went through the same signup process.

Today I got a message in the app from the host saying that I need to send pictures of all ids of the guests to an email they provided (@gmail.com).

They say if I don't do that I won't get details like where the keys to the apartment are, etc. Is it OK to provide those pictures or is it a problem?

---

Edit: Country is Italy and the property is an apartment. Not a single room in a property.

Comment: In some countries it’s mandatory for hosts to obtain guest details including eg passport number. Hosts can specify ‘government-issued ID required’ as a booking condition, but I’m not sure they can ask to see it before you arrive. If I were you, I’d contact the AirBnb Support Team for advice. They will be able to see the message from your host and liaise with them if needed to resolve this.

Comment: I have used airbnb over 20 times and never had to send my ID before the trip. I also don't understand why you have to send them to an email when you can upload pictures to the messages in the airbnb-system. Does the host have any reviews? As already suggested I would contact AirBnB-Support.

Comment: We will not meet the host, we are getting keys and a code (or something like that). The host has 98 reviews and they are great in general, but not like 100% great (people list cons of the property, but they are bearable).

Comment: @IvankaTodorova in this case I would say that's pretty safe that the host will not abuse your personal information. But it's still not GDPR conform. Успех :)

Comment: Even though there might be genuine reasons (???) I don't see why you can't do it via the AirBnb platform and are going via email (which means AirBnb won't see or know what's happening, and they are quite useful in aiding you when something goes wrong with the property, so not seeing a good reason for avoiding the official AirBnb channel of communication and switching to email).

Comment: Regarding positive reviews (in case I wanted to abuse the ID photos and use those for something or simply sell them), well you can't easily find that out within the window you're allowed to leave a review and the host person could also safe guard themselves by not doing anything dodgy with the IDs until you leave them the review or the review window closes (as you can't change your review in the future). I'm not saying this particular host will be selling the ID on black market or opening accounts under your name, but I still don't see a reason why they need it or if it's genuine why email.

Comment: It probably would help if you let us know the country the property is in, and what kind of property it is. Also, as you are talking about getting the keys, I suppose this is a full property (i.e. not just a room or bed), so I'm surprised by the requirement for all your friends to be invited, to sign up, and provide their ID to Airbnb, wouldn't your own registration have been enough in that respect?

Comment: I had the same issue. An internet search told me so send a scan where you write on the ID card something like "only for the host XY/the governtment of Z" and the date.

Comment: @jcaron: As I understand, the Portugese governtment rewuires this.

Comment: You can always block out part of the document such as the photo or the machine readable section. This will make the document harder to use to for nefarious purposes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Italy, there is a legal requirement that all guests of hotels, B&Bs, rooms, etc. (including Airbnb) must be registered with the local police, so I guess it's not a matter of tourist tax but they are asking it because of this registration.

In the most recent version of the law, the host must fill in an online form to register the guests. From what I read (I don't have a hotel/airbnb myself, so maybe others with first-hand knowledge can confirm), the host must provide **name, surname, gender, birth date and place, nationality** of all occupants, but document details are required only for **one** of the guests (the "group leader").

This registration must happen **before** the guests can enter their room (although in my experience this part is not always respected).

Reference (in Italian): https://www.laleggepertutti.it/283994_cosa-registra-lhotel

So, from what I understand, they don't *need* IDs for all occupants, but they need some personal information. Probably they are asking for IDs just for their convenience: it's easier for them to read all the required information from a document, rather than asking about them and dealing with all the language issues and "how do you spell it?".

Comment: Spain has a similar law.  In fact, when GDPR became effective, I pointed out that the registration they required of us was no longer legal.  Didn’t help.  But no images were required, just info in text.  So the suggestion to blur the photos is a good one.

Comment: @WGroleau GDPR lists as one of the six possible legal bases for data treatment "processing is necessary for compliance with a legal obligation to which the controller is subject". So the fact that this registration is mandated by the local laws makes it automatically GDPR-compliant. (On the other hand, the part where they ask you to send them to a Gmail address could be illegal by itself).

Comment: As I understand GDPR, it is non-compliant in that neither we nor the Guardía Civil gave any explanation to the person giving up their personal info, nor asked for their permission.  The poorly programmed input form is still the same as it was in 2015 (the first time I used it).  Ironically, if a pilgrim was reported missing, the Guardía Civil would call us on the phone asking whether they had stayed with us (instead of just checking their database).

Comment: @WGroleau All true, but, as far as I understand, if you are the host, then it is up to *you* to draft a GDPR consent form and show it to the user, not the Guardia Civil. You are the data controller.

Answer (score 11):

I contacted the Airbnb support before replying to my host.

They called me within an hour, confirming that I need to provide copies of our IDs as the host needs to file for tourist tax with them in the local police department or something like that.

They assured me that it's needed and there's no way around it. Especially if I am not meeting the host in person.

Comment: I used an AirBnb flat rental in Naples, Italy two years ago. The host didn’t ask us to provide ID in advance, she came to see us in the flat shortly after we picked up the keys from the concierge. So I guess the request from your host is more to do with them not meeting you in person than having to file for tourist tax before you actually arrive. I’d be unhappy about sending my ID documents by email, don’t know if you could use the AirBnb app instead?

Comment: I am not an expert (far from it) but this sounds to me like a violation of GDPR.  I spent some time in hospitality in ____ where the government required us to input data into an online database.  When GDPR made it illegal, we never received any message from the government about it, nor did a couple of websites saying we had to do it get updated.

Comment: They answered the part about whether you need to provide the ID, what about the part of having to use email as a means to provide it instead of AirBnb chat which is more secure?

Answer (score 6):

Just adding some extra context.

Hosts must register guests to "Guests portal" in the official Police website https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/PortaleAlloggiati/ so guests information is required. Hosts should check your ID upon arrival and insert those information in the "Guests portal".

It is illegal to ask for documents through email or photograph/scan/copy them unless they make you sign some kind of privacy consensus form.
https://community.withairbnb.com/t5/Supporto/come-richiedere-i-documenti-agli-ospiti/td-p/584782

It's pretty common for hosts to ask documents by email though, as it makes their life easier. Hosts who comply with the law must deal with several public administration websites  to input guests information.